# Execution request on button

Tags: javascript

I have a small problem of requete mysql I explain I would like to put one day the column "status" via a checkbox by clicking a plus button, then I click the button nothing happens.
I would like to know if my code is good
Requette.php

```
<?php
/* Database connection start */
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "Mm101010";
$dbname = "smartphone";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

/* Database connection end */


$data_ids = $_REQUEST['data_ids'];
$data_id_array = explode(",", $data_ids);
if(!empty($data_id_array)) {
    foreach($data_id_array as $Or_Affectation) {
        $sql = "UPDATE abonnements SET Statut = 'Non Affecté' ";
        $sql.=" WHERE Or_Affectation = '".$Or_Affectation."'";
        $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("supr_Affect.php: Suprimer Affectation");
    }
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>Smartphone</title>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bouton.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var dataTable = $('#vu_affect_empl').DataTable( {
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "columnDefs": [ {
                          "targets": 0,
                          "orderable": false,
                          "searchable": false

                        } ],
                    "ajax":{
                        url :"Affectation.php", // json datasource
                        type: "post",  // method  , by default get
                        error: function(){  // error handling
                            $(".vu_affect_empl-error").html("");
                            $("#vu_affect_empl").append('<tbody class="vu_affect_empl-error"><tr><th colspan="3"></th></tr></tbody>');
                            $("#vu_affect_empl_processing").css("display","none");

                        }
                    }
                } );


                $("#action_ligne").on('click',function() { // bulk checked
                    var status = this.checked;
                    $(".updateRow").each( function() {
                        $(this).prop("checked",status);
                    });
                });

                $('#update_affect').on("click", function(event){ // triggering delete one by one
                    if( $('.updateRow:checked').length > 0 ){  // at-least one checkbox checked
                        var ids = [];
                        $('.updateRow').each(function(){
                            if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                                ids.push($(this).val());
                            }
                        });
                        var ids_string = ids.toString();  // array to string conversion
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "supr_Affect.php",
                            data: {data_ids:ids_string},
                            success: function(result) {
                                dataTable.draw(); // redrawing datatable
                            },
                            async:false
                        });
                    }
                });
            } );
        </script>
        <style>
            div.container {
                margin: 0 auto;
                max-width:760px;
            }
            div.header {
                margin: 100px auto;
                line-height:30px;
                max-width:760px;
            }
            body {
                background: #f7f7f7;
                color: #333;
                font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue",HelveticaNeue,Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
            }       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
   <h2 align="center">Affectation</h2><br/><br/><br/>

   <center>
      <button href="Abonnement.php" id="update_affect" class="bouton_dans_page">Abonnement</button>
      <a href="Employe.php" class="bouton_dans_page"> Employe</a>
      <a href="Equipement.php" class="bouton_dans_page"> Equipement</a>
      <a href="Modele.php" class="bouton_dans_page"> Modele</a>
      <a href="Nouvelle_Affectation.php" class="bouton_dans_page"> Nouvelle Affectation</a>
      <a href="Employe.php" class="bouton_dans_page"> Employe</a>
      <a href="Menu_Smartphone.html" class="bouton_dans_page"> Menu Smarphone</a>
            <table id="vu_affect_empl"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" width="100%"><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><input type="checkbox" id='action_ligne' /></th>
                            <th>USER ID</th>
                            <th>Nom</th>
                            <th>Prenom</th>
                            <th>Num SIM</th>
                            <th>PIN Terminal</th>
                            <th>PIN SIM</th>
                            <th>Num EMEI</th>
                            <th>Date Debut</th>
                            <th>Date Fin</th>
                            <th>Vitre</th>
                            <th>Coque</th>
                            <th>Support Vehicule</th>
                            <th>Actif</th>
                            <th>Statut</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
            </table><br><br>
<button type="button" class="Menu" id="update_affect" name="Supprimer_affect">Suprimer Affectation</button>
<button class="Menu" type="button" id="C_R_E" onclick="javascript:Confirmer" name="C_R_E">Confirmer Retour Equipement</button>
<a href="Equipement_Modal.php" class="Menu" id="R_E" name="R_E"> Remplacer Equipement</a>
<button class="Menu" type="button" id="A_S_L" name="A_S_L">Ajout et Supression Ligne</button>
<button class="Menu" type="button" id="C_R_A" name="C_R_A">Confirmer Retour Abonnement</button>
<button class="Menu" type="button" id="Reaff_Equip" name="Reaff_Equip">Reaffectation Equipement</button>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

thank you

Comment: First do some basic debugging: check console for JavaScript errors, check the request and its response in the Network tab of devtools... You can't just paste your code and ask to "check if my code is good"

Comment: Can you cut this down? There's a ton of code that's just not relevant to the question and makes it hard to understand exactly what's failing

Comment: It's very likely that you want to get a specific ID and fill it in the array (ids). But, from what I see, you are passing to that array the values of the combobox.. You should add a data-id or something like that and on each combobox try to pass that data-id value

Comment: You can show me an example

Answer (score 0):

```
                $('.updateRow').each(function(){
                    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        ids.push($(this).data('yourID'));
                    }
                });
```

I think that you are passing the wrong information regarding the ID's you need (you are using `ids.push($(this).val());` and if the value of the checkbox does not contain the ID needed you will not get anything).

EDIT:
Change the class of the checkbox at line:

```
$nestedData[] = "<input type='checkbox' class='deleteRow' value='".$row['Or_Affectation']."'  /> N°".$i ;
```

to

```
$nestedData[] = "<input type='checkbox' class='updateRow' value='".$row['Or_Affectation']."'  /> N°".$i ;
```

Comment: Its still does not work. I wonder if its does not come from the query

Comment: could you show us the code where you build up the table rows? or at least the part where you fill in the checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "Mm101010";
$dbname = "smartphone";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

$requestData = $_REQUEST;


$columns = array( 
    0 => 'USER_ID', 
    1 => 'Nom',
    2 => 'Prenom',
    3 => 'Num_SIM', 
    4 => 'PIN_Terminal',
    5 => 'PIN_SIM', 
    6 => 'Num_IMEI',
    7 => 'Date_Debut', 
    8 => 'Date_Fin',
    9 => 'Vitre', 
   11 => 'Coque',
   12 => 'Support_Vehicule', 
   13 => 'Actif',
   14 => 'Statut'

);


$sql = "SELECT Or_Affectation ";
$sql.=" FROM vu_affect_empl";
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Affectation.php: get employees");
$totalData = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$totalFiltered = $totalData;

$sql = "SELECT Or_Affectation, USER_ID, Nom, Prenom, Num_SIM, PIN_Terminal, PIN_SIM, Num_IMEI, Date_Debut, Date_Fin, Vitre, Coque, Support_Vehicule, Actif,  Statut ";
$sql.=" FROM vu_affect_empl WHERE 1=1";

if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {  
    $sql.=" AND ( USER_ID LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";    
    $sql.=" OR Num_SIM LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";

    $sql.=" OR Nom LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' )";
}
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Affectation.php: get employees");
$totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";

$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Affectation.php: get employees");

$data = array();
$i=1+$requestData['start'];
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  
    $nestedData=array(); 

$nestedData[] = "<input type='checkbox' class='updateRow' value='".$row['Or_Affectation']."'  /> N°".$i ;
    $nestedData[] = $row["USER_ID"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["Nom"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["Prenom"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["Num_SIM"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["PIN_Terminal"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["PIN_SIM"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["Num_IMEI"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["Date_Debut"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["Date_Fin"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["Vitre"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["Coque"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["Support_Vehicule"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["Actif"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["Statut"];

    $data[] = $nestedData;
    $i++;
}



$json_data = array(
            "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), 
            "data"            => $data   
            );

echo json_encode($json_data);  

?>
```